# Protecting an API with Scopes (oauth2orize, passport, express, Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, express, scope, passport.js, oauth2orize

I'm trying to create an API with node/express, and secure it with Passport and oauth2orize. I've got the API working, I've got the oauth2 stuff working, but I can't seem to figure out how to implement securing API methods with scopes.

The oauth2orize token hander-outer:

```
server.exchange(oauth2orize.exchange.password(function (client, username, password, scope, done) {
scope = scope || ['unauthorized'];
db.collection('oauth_users').findOne({username: username}, function (err, user) {
    if (err) return done(err);
    if (!user) return done(null, false);
    for (i in scope)
        if(user.scope.indexOf(scope[i]) < 0) return done(null, false);
    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, res) {
        if (!res) return done(null, false);

        var token = utils.uid(256)
        var refreshToken = utils.uid(256)
        var tokenHash = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(token).digest('hex')
        var refreshTokenHash = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(refreshToken).digest('hex')

        var expirationDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + (3600 * 1000))

        db.collection('oauth_access_tokens').save({token: tokenHash, expirationDate: expirationDate, clientId: client.clientId, userId: username, scope: scope}, function (err) {
            if (err) return done(err)
            db.collection('oauth_refresh_tokens').save({refreshToken: refreshTokenHash, clientId: client.clientId, userId: username}, function (err) {
                if (err) return done(err)
                done(null, token, refreshToken, {expires_in: expirationDate})
            })
        })
    })
}) }))
```

The passport bearer token checker:

```
passport.use("accessToken", new BearerStrategy(
{passReqToCallback: true},
function (req, accessToken, done) {
    console.dir(req.params);
    var accessTokenHash = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(accessToken).digest('hex')
    db.collection('oauth_access_tokens').findOne({token: accessTokenHash}, function (err, token) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        if (!token) return done(null, false);
        if (new Date() > token.expirationDate) {
            db.collection('oauth_access_tokens').remove({token: accessTokenHash}, function (err) { done(err) });
        } else {
            db.collection('oauth_users').findOne({username: token.userId}, function (err, user) {
                if (err) return done(err);
                if (!user) return done(null, false);
                // no use of scopes for no
                var info = { scope: '*' }
                done(null, user, info);
            })
        }
    })
}))
```

The API security:

```
router.get('/restricted', passport.authenticate('accessToken', { scope: "unauthorized", session: false }), function (req, res) {
res.send("Restricted Function");})
```

I can find no example of accessing the "scope" option passed in passport.authenticate to passport.use. I was thinking it was in the req object, but I can't find it in there. Any help?

Comment: Hey how did you end up using scope in this stack? I have the same problem but can't figure out how to utilize scopes.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late. But thought this might help. The ***info*** object that you pass as the third parameter can be used from the middleware as ***req.authInfo***. If you have *scope* attached with the *user* object or if you have declared it at *passport.authenticate* initialize level, you can pass it through this parameter and make use of in the middleware. Please have a look at this link [Usage of scopes](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http-bearer/issues/2)

Comment: You made my day! Thank you!